# Log4j keep on writing to the log file even there is nothing to be written?

Tags: tomcat, log4j

I have a web application deployed on tomcat server. 
I use log4j for logging. It works good.
But the problem is when there is nothing happening, log4j continuously writes the following to the log file:

```
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:13:46,617 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:13:56,620 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:06,623 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:16,626 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:26,629 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:36,632 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:46,635 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:14:56,638 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:15:06,641 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:15:16,644 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
[DEBUG] 2016-03-09 09:15:26,647 com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner - com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$DeadlockDetector@1f3e145e -- Running DeadlockDetector[Exiting. No pending tasks.]
```

I don't want these messages in log file.

Is there any solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to the above messages, the log4j was writing some other messages as well when there is nothing happening. So the log file was growing and looking awkward.
I changed the threshold value from `DEBUG` to `INFO`.
And it solved my problem, my logs look clean now.